# jquery var equals var doesnt work

Tags: jquery, equals, var

I feel kinda stupid, I tried to find an answer on here but couldn't find the right thing. Hope someone can help me.

I'm simply trying to match two different variables, so if they are the same an item should receive a new class:

```
var recentposttitle = $('#catblogoutput h2.post-title').text();
$('#sub-nav ul li a').each(function() {
  var subnavlink = $(this).attr('title');


    if (subnavlink == recentposttitle) {
        $(this).addClass('selected');

    }
});
```

Well it doesn't work. Any idea why? Appreciate it!

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"?can you provaide an example?Your code looks ok

Comment: The comparison works perfectly, but not to your expectations. What are the content of these elements?

Comment: Never underestimate what a couple of simple alerts will provide you in terms of javascript debugging power.

Comment: @OnResolve better yet, dev tools and console logs.

Comment: seems there should be really a different between `recentposttitle` and `subnavlink`.

Comment: It doesnt work in terms of adding the class to the "selected" item with the same title content as for the headline content. I tried alerts and using consols. thanks for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed. Your code is valid.

Try printing the strings to the console for help. Chances are, they don't match up.

```
var recentposttitle = $('#catblogoutput h2.post-title').text();

$('#sub-nav ul li a').each(function(){  
    var subnavlink = $(this).attr('title');     

    console.log("Post Title: '" + recentposttitle + "'");
    console.log("Menu Link: '" + subnavlink + "'");

    if(subnavlink==recentposttitle){        
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: You can substitute "alert" for "console.log" if you're unsure how to get to (or don't have) the console, that will provide a javascript popup.

Comment: Also, make sure the HTML is loaded before that script runs. Move the script to the bottom of the page or wrap the jQuery in...
$(document).ready(function() { //your code });

Comment: Thanks for that. The only difference I can see is an additional space for the post title...hmmm

Comment: Wrap your strings in `$.trim(str)` ... your IF statement would look like `if($.trim(subnavlink)==$.trim(recentposttitle)){`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in:

```
var recentposttitle = $('#catblogoutput h2.post-title').text();
```

I don't think this is what you want. Per the jquery documentation, the .text() function is defined as:

> Description: Get the combined text contents of each element in the set
>   of matched elements, **including their descendants.**

This should point you to your answer

Answer (score 0):

The code does work. I tested it, and given the correct markup it works just fine.

Check out the example, and compare the markup to your own:

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/NHexj/

Comment: thanks, my post title is something like "The Mental Break Between Architect and User" and the a title is equivalent to that: a title="The Mental Break Between Architect and User" and when I run it it gives me an error. Any idea why?

Comment: nevermind, no error, but I think its the additional space in the post title, damn now how do I get rid of that...well thanks, help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct, now we need to see the markup that goes along, because the queries in your snippet could not be matching anything in your document, depending on what it is.

For something like this, firebug or developer tools and a breakpoint in the iteration should get you sorted in no time.